# Pandas merge inner join returning empty dataframe

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe, merge

I need to merge two dataframes according to three variables, however, when I try pd.merge I get an empty dataframe as a result.

The code I've tried is:

```
new_dft = pd.merge(dfh, df,  how='inner', left_on=['Latitude','Longitude','time'], right_on = ['latitude','longitude','time'])
```

I've also tried to run:

```
new_df = pd.merge(dfh, df,  how='inner', left_on=['Latitude','time'], right_on = ['latitude','time'])
```

```
new_df1 = pd.merge(dfh, df,  how='inner', left_on=['Longitude','time'], right_on = ['longitude','time'])
```

Just to assess if there was an error in one of the variables Longitude, Latitudine or Time, but these two codes run just fine, resulting in two tables correctly merged.

However the output that I need is the one that results from the merge on the three variables...Can anyone help me out?

Comment: With `inner` you're forcing to only take the intersection of the two dataframes, which means there must be at least 1 row of `['Latitude', 'Longitude', 'time']` in `dfh` that is EXACTLY the same to a row of `['latitude','longitude','time']` in `df`. Did you try to verify this before? Also worth checking if the `dtypes` of the columns (and maybe time zones for the datetime ones) are the same. Although if that would be the issue then you wouldn't be able to do the last two merges.

Comment: You need to show representative values in the DF columns which cause the error to clarify why the result is an empty DF,